# How to read text box text set by JavaScript from code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have one ASP.net text box on my page. I am setting text property of this text box using JavaScript. Now, I want to access this text value from back-end (using C#). However, whenever I try to access it, I am getting the old value (the one set up during page load) and I am not able to get the value set by JavaScript code. 
Am I missing something here?

ASPX markup of the text box -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

JavaScript to edit this text box -

```
var txtMessage = document.getElementById("txtMessage");
txtMessage.Value = "New Value";
```

C# code to access text box text -

```
string strMessage = txtMessage.Text; // This does not return value set by above JS function
```

Comment: `.Value` should be `.value`. `.Text` should be `.text`, for a start.

Comment: @Andy the `.Text` is correct; that part is server-side C# code.

Comment: I made these changes. Still no luck. The value is getting displayed in browser. However, on back end, I am not able to get the value using text property. Also, .Text is correct as mentioned by Troy Gizzi.

Comment: @AshutoshPujari Right-click that field in the browser, select _Inspect element_, and see what the id is there. Depending on the rest of your ASPX layout, the id might be getting prefixed by something else. If so, then you'll have to include that prefix in your JavaScript.

Comment: `var txtMessage = document.getElementById("<%= txtMessage.ClientID %>");`

Comment: Thanks @Igor! I'd forgotten about that handy little property. I updated my answer to include that change too.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change this line in the JavaScript:

```
txtMessage.value = "New Value"; // the "v" in ".value" needs to be lowercase
```

---

UPDATE: I set up an ASP.NET page to make sure that the OP's code did in fact work with that one change, just to make sure I wasn't missing any other little typo. However, as Igor pointed out in his comment, it's a good practice to use the control's `ClientID` property to account for any prefixes that the .NET runtime might add to an HTML element's id.

So the two lines in your JavaScript should be changed to this (also confirmed to work correctly):

```
var txtMessage = document.getElementById("<%= txtMessage.ClientID %>");
txtMessage.value = "New Value";
```

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.Net delivers the page to be render, the name of the controls are changed by prepending a suffix that identifies the container that hold them. From JavaScript, you must ensure to get the correct ID of ASP controls by accessing the `.ClientID` property.

```
//gets the element by its ID according to ASP rules
var txtMessage = document.getElementById("<%=txtMessage.ClientID%>");

//the "value" property is lowercase
txtMessage.value = "New Value";
```